# Control-A in a code area selects more than just the code.

Tags: bug, status-declined

When I click in a code area and then press control-a, I expect to see only the code in the code panel selected.  Instead, everything on the page is selected.  If I wanted to select everything on the page, then I would not have clicked in the code area.

**Update:** this is not an issue with short pieces of code, but for longer pieces, it sure is hard to copy just the code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

using System.Collections.Specialized;

using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.EnterpriseServices;

using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Server;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geometry;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geodatabase;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Carto;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.SOESupport;


//TODO: sign the project (project properties > signing tab > sign the assembly)
//      this is strongly suggested if the dll will be registered using regasm.exe <your>.dll /codebase


namespace RestSOE1
{
    [ComVisible(true)]
    [Guid("2d1eaa1c-c07c-47f1-b97e-b0730bbbf619")]
    [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None)]
    public class RestSOE1 : ServicedComponent, IServerObjectExtension, IObjectConstruct, IRESTRequestHandler
    {
        private string soe_name;

        private IPropertySet configProps;
        private IServerObjectHelper serverObjectHelper;
        private ServerLogger logger;
        private IRESTRequestHandler reqHandler;

        public RestSOE1()
        {
            soe_name = this.GetType().Name;
            logger = new ServerLogger();
            reqHandler = new SoeRestImpl(soe_name, CreateRestSchema()) as IRESTRequestHandler;
        }

        #region IServerObjectExtension Members

        public void Init(IServerObjectHelper pSOH)
        {
            serverObjectHelper = pSOH;
        }

        public void Shutdown()
        {
        }

        #endregion

        #region IObjectConstruct Members

        public void Construct(IPropertySet props)
        {
            configProps = props;
        }

        #endregion

        #region IRESTRequestHandler Members

        public string GetSchema()
        {
            return reqHandler.GetSchema();
        }

        public byte[] HandleRESTRequest(string Capabilities, string resourceName, string operationName, string operationInput, string outputFormat, string requestProperties, out string responseProperties)
        {
            return reqHandler.HandleRESTRequest(Capabilities, resourceName, operationName, operationInput, outputFormat, requestProperties, out responseProperties);
        }

        #endregion

        private RestResource CreateRestSchema()
        {
            RestResource rootRes = new RestResource(soe_name, false, RootResHandler);

            RestOperation sampleOper = new RestOperation("sampleOperation",
                                                      new string[] { "parm1", "parm2" },
                                                      new string[] { "json" },
                                                      SampleOperHandler);

            rootRes.operations.Add(sampleOper);

            return rootRes;
        }

        private byte[] RootResHandler(NameValueCollection boundVariables, string outputFormat, string requestProperties, out string responseProperties)
        {
            responseProperties = null;

            JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
            result.AddString("hello", "world");

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.ToJson());
        }

        private byte[] SampleOperHandler(NameValueCollection boundVariables,
                                                  JsonObject operationInput,
                                                      string outputFormat,
                                                      string requestProperties,
                                                  out string responseProperties)
        {
            responseProperties = null;

            string parm1Value;
            bool found = operationInput.TryGetString("parm1", out parm1Value);
            if (!found || string.IsNullOrEmpty(parm1Value))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parm1");

            string parm2Value;
            found = operationInput.TryGetString("parm2", out parm2Value);
            if (!found || string.IsNullOrEmpty(parm2Value))
                throw new ArgumentNullException("parm2");

            JsonObject result = new JsonObject();
            result.AddString("parm1", parm1Value);
            result.AddString("parm2", parm2Value);

            return Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result.ToJson());
        }


    }
}
```

Comment: Select, then Ctrl-C is all that worked for me.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it more clear that this is an issue when there's a lot of code, see revision. I thought there is an html tag that allows ctrl-a to select only what's in the div.

Comment: could you provide other sites which do this correctly? I'm guessing it requires trapping things in Javascript and probably the implementation can be copied from elsewhere.

Comment: Actually, maybe this should be a feature request, just a button that appears next to long code listings that allows user to copy to clipboard.  I see now that ctrl-a is only expected to stay within a text area when the text is editable. (Like now as I type this comment).

Comment: Sounds like the request for a code library link would be appropriate  ( http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/462/could-we-have-a-code-library )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> When I click in a code area and then press control-a, I expect to see only the code in the code panel selected. Instead, everything on the page is selected. If I wanted to select everything on the page, then I would not have clicked in the code area.

That isn't how HTML selection works, though -- this might be an unreasonable expectation.

Also bear in mind we discourage posting *giant* blocks of code -- just post the relevant parts, the stuff necessary for the question or answer, and link to the complete code in pastebin or somewhere else off-site.

Answer (score 3):

At https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/821/easy-way-to-copy-code-block/891#891, Martin Scharrer has written a Greasemonkey script that inserts a `select all` button under every chunk of code. When you click on it, the code chunk is selected, and you can copy it by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>c</kbd>. In its current form, the script only works on tex.stackexchange.com, but by inserting the line `// @include        http://*.stackexchange.com/*` near the beginning, it can be made to work on all stackexchange sites.

Answer (score 1):

For Firefox users, a simple solution *for code within scrollable windows*, such as your example, is to click in front of the first character of the code window and hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Page Down</kbd> until it reaches the bottom of the window. Voila, all the code is selected and you can then copy-paste as usual.

**Note:** You may have to use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Down Arrow</kbd> to get the last line. At least that was my experience with Firefox.

**Note 2:** This does not seem to work with Chrome or IE (tested on Windows 7).